# Why can't my java code make https request inside of JBoss?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jboss, jboss5.x, aws-lambda

I have a AWS api gateway url which is https, my web application is running on jboss 5.1.1.

Inside one of the services in the app, I use apache's HttpClient to make a GET request to this api gateway url. I'm getting some sort of handshake failure. What should I do in order to fix this?

Edit:

Now I am testing on my local machine. I am able to access the api gateway with no issues via a basic jar file; ie main method that makes the http request. I am able to access the api gateway url via browser with no issues.

Comment: 'Getting some sort of handshake failure' is not a problem description. Try again.

Comment: @EJP idk what else to add, that's all i see on the stacktrace: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure, if i knew what else to post i would...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS API Gateway uses TLSv1.2 encryption, my jboss was running on Java 1.6 which doesn't support TLSv1.2; it only support up to TLSv1, so the handshake will always fail.

Refer to https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https for additional info on Java and HTTPS.